# Sending int[]s between Java and C

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I have some image processing Java code in Android that acts upon two large int arrays. Most of the time, Java is fast enough but I need to use C via JNI and the NDK to speed up a few operations.

The only way I know that I can pass the data from the int arrays to C is to use ByteBuffer.allocateDirect to create a new buffer, copy the data to that and then make the C code act upon the buffer.

However, I cannot see any way I can manipulate the data in this buffer in Java as if the buffer was an int[] or a byte[]. For example, a call to ByteBuffer.array() will fail on the newly created buffer. Is there any way to make this work?

I have limited memory and want to reduce how many arrays/buffers I need. For example, it would be nice if I could use IntBuffer.wrap(new int[...]) to create the buffer and then manipulate the array backing the buffer directly in Java but I cannot do this because the only thing that seems to work here for JNI is ByteBuffer.allocateDirect.

Are there any other ways to send data back and forth between C and Java? Can I somehow allocate memory on the C side and have Java send data directly to there?

Edit: A benchmark comparing buffer use to int[] use:

```
int size = 1000;
IntBuffer allocateDirect = java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * size).asIntBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
  for (int x = 0; x < size; ++x)
  {
    int v = allocateDirect.get(x);
    allocateDirect.put(x, v + 1);
  }
}

int[] intArray = new int[size];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
  for (int x = 0; x < size; ++x)
  {
    int v = intArray[x];
    intArray[x] = v + 1;
  }
}
```

On a Droid phone, the buffer version takes ~10 seconds to finish and the array version takes ~0.01 seconds.

Comment: Wait, what's wrong with [`ByteBuffer.asIntBuffer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#asIntBuffer%28%29)?  Do you really need to have an `int[]`?

Comment: ... and furthermore, you can call .array() on the IntBuffer if you wanted to.

Comment: .array() throws an Unsupported exception for both ByteBuffer and IntBuffer for directly allocated arrays in Java. I really want access to an int[] so I can do some of the less intensive image processing stuff in Java e.g. convert an image to black and white by checking which pixels are above/below a brightness threshold. Using IntBuffer get/put for every pixel would be too slow in Android as well as being clumsy.

Comment: @rebeccaT, change your code to use IntBuffer instead of int[] and use direct buffers

Comment: @Mike, you can not use array() for direct buffer, for very obvious reasons

Comment: @bestsss: Could you elaborate on what you mean? Using IntBuffer.get/put to modify/retrieve pixels values is going to very slow and cumbersome and is not a solution to my problem.

Comment: @rebeccaT, if put/get is so slow, there is something terribly wrong. Those methods are supposed to be inlined and compiled to quite simple CPU instructions *w/o* any virtual method invocation. Yes, I offer you to dump the int[] and always use direct IntBuffer

Comment: @rebeccaT, >>Are there any other ways to send data back and forth between C and Java? Can I somehow allocate memory on the C side and have Java send data directly to there?<< this is what exactly direct buffers are for

Comment: @bestsss: I'm using Android so the function calls are not going to get inlined or compiled to native code (unless the phone has the latest Android version but I cannot rely on this). I benchmarked it and it's slow by an order of magnitude. You generally need to avoid function calls during inner loops in image processing functions here e.g. even Math.max(int,int) slow things down.

Comment: @rebeccaT, that sounds very odd to me. I guess you did not test in debug. I need to check (our company does develop on android as well). Yet, not having inlined functions and generally avoiding very simple optimizations is beyond ridiculous.

Comment: @bestsss: See my edited original post for a benchmark showing that buffer usage is several orders of magnitude slower than array use in Android (running version 2.1 i.e. no JIT). Any other suggestions? :-\ I agree the situation is pretty ridiculous. I'm close to just having to implement all the array operations in C. For example, even XORing two arrays together is slow in Java but fast in C on Android without a JIT.

Comment: @rebeccaT, overall Java is a bad choice w/o JIT. I'd not consider it a viable language w/o JIT. Also the micro-benchmark in normal conditions should be considered dead-code for the int array (but not for the directbuffer). To make sure it's not ignored, after the loop, make one more and sum the content and print it somewhere.

Comment: @rebeccaT, if you need to resort on JNI, here some helpful links, you may know 'em already: http://android.wooyd.org/JNIExample/ a blog w/ example http://blog.jayway.com/2010/01/25/boosting-android-performance-using-jni/ and the original JNI from SUN: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/objtypes.html#4099

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/objtypes.html, use JNI's `Get/Release<TYPE>ArrayElements(...)`

In this example, I will pass an array ( for argument's sake, it's `int array = new int[10]` and then fill it with 0-9

```
 JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL 
 Java_IntArray_doStuffArray(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jintArray arr)
 {

     // initializations, declarations, etc
     jint *c_array;
     jint i = 0;

     // get a pointer to the array
     c_array = (*env)->GetIntArrayElements(env, arr, NULL);

     // do some exception checking
     if (c_array == NULL) {
         return -1; /* exception occurred */
     }

     // do stuff to the array
     for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
         c_array[i] = i;
     }

     // release the memory so java can have it again
     (*env)->ReleaseIntArrayElements(env, arr, c_array, 0);

     // return something, or not.. it's up to you
     return 0;
 }
```

Study section 3.3, and specifically 3.3.2 -- this will allow you to get a pointer to the array in java's memory, modify it, and release it, in effect allowing you to modify the array in native code.

I've just used it in my own project (with short arrays) and it works great :)

Comment: thanks this code helped me connect to siglib library method for FIR filters

Comment: to get the count
int arrayLength = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, arr);

Comment: When I try this, the Java doStuffArray(arr) returns before the native Java_IntArray_doStuffArray completes. What do I need to do to block the java side until the native side completes?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using direct allocated buffers, you can access the backing array directly from C, using the `GetDirectBufferAddress` function. This prevents the possibility of copying regions of the area.

You can operate on the returned address directly as you would a normal C array, and it will directly modify the Java direct-allocated buffer.

Then, as ephemient states, you can use ByteBuffer.asIntBuffer() and family to access the buffer in a way that emulates arrays of the various Java primitives.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/jni-14.html

Answer (score 4):

You can use callback for sending the data from native layer to Java.

In Java layer: in my native class I have following methods:

```
//Native method
public native String getStrData(int size);

//Callback method
public void addData(char[] native_data, int size) {

    ...

}
```

In Native layer: in my native implementation:

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_pkg_NativeClass_getStrData 
   (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint size) {
     ...

     jclass native_class;           /* Callback: native class */
     jmethodID native_method_id;    /* Callback: native method id */
     jcharArray row;                /* Callback: native data */

     ...

    /* Start Callback: Native to Java  */   
    native_class = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);
    native_method_id = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, native_class, "addData", "([CI)V");
    if (native_method_id == 0) {
        return (jstring)ERR_NATIVE_METHODID;
    }
    row = (jcharArray)(*env)->NewCharArray(env, size);
    /* jc has the data to be sent to Java */
    (*env)->SetCharArrayRegion(env, (jcharArray)row, (jsize)0, size, (jchar *)jc);

    (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, obj, native_method_id, row, size);
    /* End Callback */

     ...
}
```

Comment: Could you please mention, what type is `jc`? Is it `char* jc`?

Comment: @dma_k : In my case 'jc' was an array of known size.

Comment: Could you give a hint, how do you operate with `jc` (e.g. set the character data)? I look here and there for examples of using `SetCharArrayRegion()`, but can't find a complete example of how to create/initialize an array of `jchar`s (for example, from ASCII 1-byte string, `char*`). Thanks